# How to use mPDF in YII, when I want to generate PDF file from HTML?

Tags: php, pdf, yii, mpdf

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A4');
$html= $this->renderPartial('poPdfTemplate', array('pdfValues'=>$ponumberData,'po_number'=>$po_number), true);
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html,0);
//$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html);
$mPDF1->Output();
```

The above code is using for generating PDF with YII framework.

Answer (score 0):

First two lines will create css `$pdf_style` and html file `$pdf_part` and PDF will be write this file.

Include these 2 variables in the `WriteHTML` function.

```
    $pdf_style = \Yii::$app->view->renderFile(PROTECTEDPATH . 'common/views/contract/style.css', $data);
    $pdf_part = \Yii::$app->view->renderFile(PROTECTEDPATH . 'common/views/contract/file.tpl', $data);


    $mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8','A4');

    $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
    $mpdf->baseScript = 1;  // Use values in classes/ucdn.php  1 = LATIN
    $mpdf->autoVietnamese = true;
    $mpdf->autoArabic = true;
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;

    $mpdf->SetMargins(null,null,40);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align:right"><img src="'. DOCROOT  .'images/logo_contract.png" height="68" /></div>');

    $mpdf->setFooter(' | www.facebook.com | {PAGENO}');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pdf_style.'<div class="wrapper">'.$pdf_part.'</div>');

    $mpdf->Output('Contract-'.date("iYsmd"), $action, $dest);
```

Comment: i want to load view not directly generate HTML to PDF and its needed form submit only.

Comment: put this code inside a controller and set form variables in to the $data and pass to view file. (2nd line)

Comment: $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A4');
$html= $this->renderPartial('NAME OF TEMPLATE', array('pdfValues'=>'passing variable'), true);
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html);
$mPDF1->Output('podetails.pdf', 'D');